# Send mulipart/form-data request for mp4upload Curl

Tags: curl, multipartform-data

I'm looking for a way to use curl to upload an video (`test.mp4` located at `C:\admin\videos\`) to the MP4UPLOAD server(s). When I submit an upload manually (using open file dialog), the following header processes the upload (some values are changed because of privacy reasons):

```
#(2)
#General
Request URL:https://www3.mp4upload.com/cgi-bin/upload.cgi?upload_type=file
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

#Request Headers
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryUYmnnrteTBA8i9Ps
Origin:https://www.mp4upload.com
Referer:https://www.mp4upload.com/?op=upload
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36

#Query String Parameters
upload_type=file

#Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryUYmnnrteTBA8i9Ps
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sess_id"

12345abcde
------WebKitFormBoundaryUYmnnrteTBA8i9Ps
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="utype"

reg
------WebKitFormBoundaryUYmnnrteTBA8i9Ps
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_descr"


------WebKitFormBoundaryUYmnnrteTBA8i9Ps
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_public"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryUYmnnrteTBA8i9Ps
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="link_rcpt"


------WebKitFormBoundaryUYmnnrteTBA8i9Ps
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="link_pass"


------WebKitFormBoundaryUYmnnrteTBA8i9Ps
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to_folder"


------WebKitFormBoundaryUYmnnrteTBA8i9Ps
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_0"; filename="test.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4


------WebKitFormBoundaryUYmnnrteTBA8i9Ps--
```

So how do I make such an upload request with the headers given above using curl/php (assuming it's possible)?

**EDIT 1**

So using chrome, I retrieved the following curl line.

```
curl -k 'https://www13.mp4upload.com/cgi-bin/upload.cgi?upload_type=file' -H 'Referer: https://www.mp4upload.com/?op=upload' -H 'Origin: https://www.mp4upload.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarykXmBSfC4cYG13IWT' --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundarykXmBSfC4cYG13IWT\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="sess_id"\r\n\r\n12345abcde\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarykXmBSfC4cYG13IWT\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="utype"\r\n\r\nreg\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarykXmBSfC4cYG13IWT\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file_descr"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarykXmBSfC4cYG13IWT\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file_public"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarykXmBSfC4cYG13IWT\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="link_rcpt"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarykXmBSfC4cYG13IWT\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="link_pass"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarykXmBSfC4cYG13IWT\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="to_folder"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarykXmBSfC4cYG13IWT\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file_0"; filename="test.mp4"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarykXmBSfC4cYG13IWT--\r\n' --compressed
```

Now the first thing I noticed that the random string at `WebKitFormBoundary` changes everytime you submit a new request. But is there any meaning behind the random string or can I just create a randomish string myself?
The second thing is that, I can't seem to find that the `test.mp4` file is from the directory `C:\admin\videos\`. How should I specify that I want to upload a file from that directory?

**EDIT 2**

So I found another method to post form data using `-F`. This way I can upload the video even to my own account (using `sess_id`).

```
curl -X POST -F "sess_id=1234abcde" -F "file_0=@C:\admin\videos\test.mp4;Type=video/mp4" -k https://www13.mp4upload.com/cgi-bin/upload.cgi?upload_type=file
```

I determined this is the easiest way for me to do it, so I leave it at this.

Comment: From my experience you can avoid a lot of hassle using Guzzle Library instead of working with curl directly (http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html?highlight=file). It surely is possible. The first header is called a preflight request. It does not hold any data but needs to return a 200 OK preliminary to the original request.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the first header. Regarding the other thing, I just want to try to use curl directly because I think I'll learn from doing it this way then using libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the following:

```
curl -X POST -F "sess_id=1234abcde" -F "file_0=@C:\admin\videos\test.mp4;Type=video/mp4" -k https://www13.mp4upload.com/cgi-bin/upload.cgi?upload_type=file
```